# Getting "Specified file cannot be found" error when mstest is invoked using Process.Start()

Tags: c#

```
 public bool InvokeMSTest()
 {
    //string str = " /testcontainer: D:\\test.dll";
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "MSTest.exe", 
        WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual  Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\\", 
        UseShellExecute = true,
        //Arguments = str,
    };
    Process.Start(startInfo);
    return true;
}
```

When I run this method using a Console Application, it throws "The specified file cannot be found" error when it attempts Process.Start(startInfo). I have confirmed that MsTest.exe does exist in the workingDirectory path provided. what am I doing wrong? If I just copy the same exe to another path and invoke, it just works fine.
Please help

Comment: You have two spaces in "Visual  Studio" and an extra slash at the end. Are you *sure* you're copying it when you try it elsewhere?

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. You are right. It was the issue with the path where an extra space existed.